# (Meteorjs/React) check if user is logged in

Tags: meteor, reactjs, authentication

right now I'm trying to create a login System in Meteor and React.
I want to display different Content, depending on wether or not the user is logged in.

```
export default class LoginForm extends Component {

 render() {
    if (Meteor.userId() === null) return( // if user is not logged in
       display HTML stuff);
    }

    return( // user is logged in
         display other stuff
    );
 }
}
```

this does not work as Meteor.userId() is always undefined after logging in.

Are there other possibilities? I've this in blaze:

```
  {{#if currentUser}} doStuff{{/if}}
```

Is is possible to use it in React as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of react-meteor-data I used ultimatejs:tracker-react

export default class LoginForm extends TrackerReact(Component) {

```
render() {
  if(Meteor.user())return (...); // user logged in
  if (Meteor.user()===null)return(...); // user logged out 
  //else page is connecting to backend
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The [react-meteor-data](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/react-meteor-data) package is designed for the integration. The [Meteor guide](https://guide.meteor.com/react.html#data) explains this in more detail.

Meteor data should be passed in as props to the component. The component should re-render itself based on changes to the props.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Meteor.user()){
}
```

or

```
if(Meteor.userId()){
}
```

should check the logged in user

```
 export default class LoginForm extends Component {

render() {
if (Meteor.userId()){
 let elementToBeRendered = 
//your elements
<form></form>
}
else{
let elementToBeRendered = //your other elements
}
return (
{elementToBeRendered}
)
 }
}
```

should do for you

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check by using `Meteor.loggingIn()` it return true or false.

in your component (LoginForm) you can check like this

```
        state = {
                isLoggedIn: false,
            }

            componentDidMount() {
                this.setState({ isLoggedIn: Meteor.loggingIn() });
            }
render(){
    return(
          <div>
             <b>{isLoggedIn ? is login : is not login}</b>
          </div>
);
```